# Modelio class diagram compartments

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram, modelio

I need help about Modelio UML Tool Class diagram components. Normal a class diagram in other modelling tools have 3 compartments. The top compartment contains the name of the class. The middle compartment contains the attributes of the class. The bottom compartment contains the operations the class can execute. But modelio has 4th compartments I need to know that why it is. I have a software project contains UML diagrams and I need to explain this stuff.

[image]

I checked their tutorials but couldnt have any answer.

Comment: A class can have up to 5 compartment and be compatible with the norm, see my answer. Add a link to a picture showing a compartment disturbing you if you need help

Comment: Here is the image [Link](https://pasteboard.co/Igu16Wt.png) . Which

Comment: Note the name does not count as a compartment, the compartment is empty on your link, it can be for the receptions or the internal structure (refer to my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Normal a class diagram in other modelling tools have 3 compartments

no, from [UML formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) §11.4.4 Notation

> A Class has four mandatory compartments: attributes, operations, receptions (see 9.2.4) and internal structure (see
>   11.2.4). A Class may also have optional compartments as described for Classifiers in general (see 9.2.4)

Comment: Hello,thank you for your answer. but what is exactly receptions and internal structures?

Comment: @ezgi better look at the norm, I put the link to the _formal_ and the quotation indicates the § ;-)

Comment: @ezgi Shortly reception is about the receipt signals (I do not show it in [BoUML](https://bouml.fr/index.html) BTW). The internal structure shows the including parts and connectors

Comment: Strange. I never read this paragraph. This is the first time I hear the term _receptions_. From my work with EA I had the assumption that the number of compartments is arbitrary. And looking at the pictures in the UML spec you don't see the "mandatory 4" but (right below that citation above) there are classes with zero and 2 compartments.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Yes that _mandatory_ is strange, probably it is wrongly written and they wanted to say a tool conformed to UML has to manage them (this is not my case), not to draw them in all cases.

Comment: @ThomasKilian :  Bruno's assumption is correct. Section 9.2.4.1 says:  ``Some compartments in Classifier shapes are mandatory and shall be supported by tools that exhibit concrete syntax conformance. Others are optional, in the sense that a conforming tool may not support such compartments.``
The same section also states: ``Any compartment may be suppressed.``

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Thanks for the insight :-) Those OMG guys have definitely room to improve their documentation. Though looking at the time for fixing my reported bugs I will probably not see that in my life time.